# rewriting old-school query strings to modern cakephp URLs

Tags: url, cakephp, query-string, routes

A plea for your indulgence.  I have searched for answers and tried many things, so I now humbly turn here for help.  It should be simple:  I'm moving to CakePhp and I want to redirect my old query strings (action=show&id=2) to groovy cake URLs (/Feature/view/2).

I've tried this in the .htaccess file in the webroot:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=show&id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule /Features/view/%1? [R,L]
```

No love.  I also tried:

```
RewriteRule action=show&id=([0-9]+) /Features/view/$1 [L]
```

No love.

I tried Cakephp's routes.php with:

```
Router::connect('index.php?action=show&id=([0-9]+)',array('controller' => 'features', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => $1));
```

But I've seen no evidence that regex can be used that way in routes.php so that was really just throwing up a prayer.

It's possible to do this.  Right?  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it within router.php!

Maybe, you can get away with:

```
Router::connect('?action=:action&id=:id', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'myController', 
        'action' => 'myAction',
    ), 
    array(
        'action' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
    )
);
```

Or (probably better) a series of more specific forms like:

```
Router::connect('?action=show&id=:id', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'features', 
        'action' => 'view',
    ), 
    array(
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
    )
);
```

In this case, `action` and `id` would be available in `$this->request->params` in myController (and in the case of a standard like `id`, there might even be automagic to help!)

Though I'm not sure that the routing elements (:foo) will pick up GET params like that..

Alternatively, you could send everything to one controller anyway, and you should find the GET parameters are listed in `$this->request->params['url']`, so you can route everything in the controller (to other controllers, I guess).

Doesn't sound pretty either way, but I understand you want to keep some legacy urls running!